# Excel - search text within matrix with just part of the text

Tags: excel, search, match

I'm looking for a way for matching two arrays in Excel, where the lookup value "bigger" is than the value in the searched matrix. Here's an example:

```
Matrix   Value   wanted Result
S1       S3      S3
S2       S3.1    S3
S3       U2.2    U2
U1       U3.a    U3
U2
U3
```

So my result is the matching Item in the Matrix. All Items are text strings.
I tried with the Match function but it works only if the Matrix is sorted alphabetically, which isn't the case.
[Match(Value;Matrix)]
Any Ideas?

Comment: Is it true that ***all*** data under `Value` is present under `Matrix`? It seems you could just get text *before* a dot. Is this true?

Comment: It's usually true but not always, unfortunately. If a Value is not present in the matrix, I'd get an error but it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Use `INDEX`/`AGGREGATE`:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(14,6,(SEARCH($A$2:$A$7,B2)*ROW($A$2:$A$7)),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, could you explain what the function aggregate does in this case? I tried transposing your solution to my sheet and I get "0" as result. In my application, the "Matrix" column is in another sheet.

Comment: The problem was the presence of zeros in the matrix. So I solved this using the Indirect function and referencing the matrix only to the filled section. Thanks again.